# The input to a flatten layer must be a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I had the following keras model, which was running ok:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1,1,68)))
model.add(Dense(35,activation='linear'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=.001))
model.add(Dense(nb_actions))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
```

Then, I tried to make something more elaborated, as below:

```
model = Sequential()
input1 = keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(1,1,68))
x1 = keras.layers.Dense(68, activation='linear')(input1)
x2 = keras.layers.Dense(68, activation='relu')(input1)
x3 = keras.layers.Dense(68, activation='sigmoid')(input1)
add1 = keras.layers.Add()([x1, x2, x3])
activ1 = keras.layers.advanced_activations.LeakyReLU(add1)

x4 = keras.layers.Dense(34, activation='linear')(activ1)
x5 = keras.layers.Dense(34, activation='relu')(activ1)
x6 = keras.layers.Dense(34, activation='sigmoid')(activ1)
add2 = keras.layers.Add()([x4, x5, x6])
activ2 = keras.layers.advanced_activations.LeakyReLU(add2)

x7 = keras.layers.Dense(17, activation='linear')(activ2)
x8 = keras.layers.Dense(17, activation='relu')(activ2)
x9 = keras.layers.Dense(17, activation='sigmoid')(activ2)
add2 = keras.layers.Add()([x4, x5, x6])
activ3 = keras.layers.advanced_activations.LeakyReLU(add3)

final_layer=keras.layers.Dense(nb_actions, activation='linear')(activ3)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input1, outputs=final_layer)
```

As you can see in the above code, I am keeping the same input from a Flatten layer and just summing up layers with the same number of neurons, but activated differently. My problem is when I try to run this code. I am getting always the following error:

```
Using TensorFlow backend. Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/anselmo/virtualenvironment/virtualenvironment_anselmo2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 279, in assert_input_compatibility
    K.is_keras_tensor(x)   File "/home/anselmo/virtualenvironment/virtualenvironment_anselmo2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 474, in is_keras_tensor
    str(type(x)) + '`. ' ValueError: Unexpectedly found an instance of type class keras.layers.core.Flatten. Expected a symbolic tensor instance.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 64, in <module>
    x1 = keras.layers.Dense(68, activation='linear')(input1)   File "/home/anselmo/virtualenvironment/virtualenvironment_anselmo2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 414, in __call__
    self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)   File "/home/anselmo/virtualenvironment/virtualenvironment_anselmo2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 285, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(inputs) + '. All inputs to the layer ' ValueError: Layer dense_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: class keras.layers.core.Flatten. Full input: [keras.layers.core.Flatten object at 0x7f0a145d6438]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

When I ran the previous code, the error did not happen. So why changing the network design there is this error? how can I solve it? where is my mistake here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying in the 2nd code is a Keras Functional model, and not a Sequential one. You should change the first line from `model = Sequential()` to `input1 = Input(shape=(1, 1, 68))`.

More details at the [official documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/).

Comment: The error is gone. Now I have another error: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. Probably because I am reading the data using Pandas. Can I fix this using the same code I showed in this thread? thanks.

Comment: You should convert your data to numpy arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, the error happens at the LeakyRelu activation layer (activ1 = keras.layers.advanced_activations.LeakyReLU(add1)), when I remove this part of the code, the network runs ok. If you can help me I would appreciate. Otherwise, I can open a new thread. Thanks.

Comment: I will have a look if you can show me the error with the backtrace

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):  File "main.py", line 85, in <module>
    activ1 = keras.layers.advanced_activations.LeakyReLU(add1)
  File keras/layers/advanced_activations.py", line 45, in __init__ self.alpha = K.cast_to_floatx(alpha) File keras/backend/common.py", line 110, in cast_to_floatx return np.asarray(x, dtype=_FLOATX) File "numpy/core/numeric.py", line 501, in asarray return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order) ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. Without this LeakyRelu the code runs ok :-(

Comment: This is because your syntax is wrong. It should be ```activ1 = keras.layers.advanced_activations.LeakyReLU(alpha=some_value_in_float)(add1)```.